# Python behave Gherkin Step parameter getting compile time Number expected exception

Tags: python-behave

```
Feature: Step Parameter Test

  Scenario: look up a book
    Given I search for a valid book
    Then the result page will include "success"

  Scenario: look up an invalid book
    Given I search for a invalid book
    Then the result page will include "failure"
```

Step Definition: getting exception Number expected between {}, Not considering status as parameter

```
@then('the result page will include {status}')
def step_impl(context,status):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    pass
```

**Exception Screenshot:**
[image]

I have tried even regular expression in that case getting steps undefined exception. didn't find any way to pass the string/number/double as parameter from feature file

Please do suggest if there is way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, for whatever reason, your `behave` parser is `'re'`. when typically it's `'parse'`.
In your test file add the following:

```
from behave import use_step_matcher

use_step_matcher('parse')
#the rest of your test here
#@given...
```

`behave` documentation on `use_step_matcher` [here](https://python-behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#behave.use_step_matcher).

Comment: It worked thank you so much, actually with re, {2}.                                                             
it was taking the number and was passing the value in second parameter in the method.

Comment: Thank you and well spotted.